# Is there a perfect Polish topology on the Baire space that is strictly finer than the usual topology?

Tags: metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

The question is: is there a perfect Polish topology on the Baire space $\mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$ that is strictly finer than the usual topology on $\mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$? The usual topology is the product topology on $\mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: by perfect you mean no isolated points?

Comment: Yes exactly, no isolated points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a corollary from Lemma 13.2 from “Classical Descriptive Set Theory” by Alexander Kechris.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JamesMitchell To make $\mathcal T_F$ perfect, you should take $F$ perfect.

Comment: So you  could let $F$ be the Cantor set $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}.$

Comment: Yes, because the Baire space is nowhere locally compact, no copy of Cantor set in it can be open,

Comment: Makes sense, many thanks @AlexRavsky!